# how can show count for each row in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have this table below as a result

```
   SELECT
    doctors.`name`,
    COUNT(`doctor-barge-naghs`.`code-naghs`) AS 'countEachDoctor'
    FROM
    doctors
    INNER JOIN `doctor-barge-naghs` ON `doctor-barge-naghs`.`code-doctor` = doctors.id
    GROUP BY doctors.`name`
```

[image]

and I want to calculate the SUM 'countEachDoctor' field and show
it beside of each row.

I did this

```
SELECT t1.*,(SELECT SUM(t1.countEachDoctor))
FROM(

SELECT
doctors.`name`,
COUNT(`doctor-barge-naghs`.`code-naghs`) AS 'countEachDoctor'
FROM
doctors
INNER JOIN `doctor-barge-naghs` ON `doctor-barge-naghs`.`code-doctor` = doctors.id
GROUP BY doctors.`name`) AS t1
```

[image]

it is what I wanted but unfortunately ,it just show one records,I need all records.

Comment: Don't include mathematical operators within table/column identifiers

Comment: For further help, see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) - and note that, given that this is an English language site, it can be more helpful to provide sample data in Latin script.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

IF you are not using mysql 8, you can achieve it like this:

```
   SELECT
    doctors.`name`,
    COUNT(`doctor-barge-naghs`.`code-naghs`) AS 'countEachDoctor',
    (SELECT SUM(t.countEachDoctor)
    FROM (
      SELECT
       COUNT(`doctor-barge-naghs`.`code-naghs`) AS 'countEachDoctor'
      FROM doctors
      INNER JOIN `doctor-barge-naghs` ON `doctor-barge-naghs`.`code-doctor` = doctors.id
      GROUP BY doctors.`name`) t) AS sumCount
    FROM
    doctors
    INNER JOIN `doctor-barge-naghs` ON `doctor-barge-naghs`.`code-doctor` = doctors.id
    GROUP BY doctors.`name`
```

Comment: what I needed was this :)